# Angular cli is not working

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

currently i am learning angular4 . So for this i install node js , then i do the following command in Node js commend prompt

```
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0
ng new --ng4 angullar-hello-world
```

By doing this , i created a angular project . Then for run project i type

```
ng serve
```

now the project run successfully `http://localhost:4200`

and in nod js command prompt the message is `webpack: compiled successfully` . But after this i cannot type anything in command prompt . Command prompt and project is still working good , but i cannot type any word or command . I am using windows 8 & Node v6.10.2 LTS .

[Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4FSW.jpg) 
Please any one can help

Comment: running `ng-serve` starts the webpack dev server and starts monitoring for changes to your app;  from this point, you can open your browser and go to http://localhost:4200 to see the app, and any time you change a file in the project, webpack will recompile the app automatically.  What other commands were you wanting to issue?  If you *really* need to issue more commands, `Ctrl+c` will stop the dev server....

Comment: Its supposed to work like that. Open new terminal for new commands

Comment: @Claies i want to issue ng generate component hello-world . When i press ctr+c it is asking terminate batch job. I type Y .Then i type  ng generate component hello-world .Now it's created new component but localhost:4200 is not working .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But after this i cannot type anything in command prompt

The program that waits for your input is called `shell` and when you type `ng serve` this shell program runs `ng` program and passes control to `ng`. `ng` doesn't expect any input from you so you can't type in anything. In order to be able to input again you have to:

1. either exit `ng` and pass control back to `shell` by pressing
   `Ctrl+C`, but this stops `ng` program.
2. run `ng serve` in background - `START /B ng serve` for Windows and `long-ng serve &` for Unix environments

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/591084/297708) for running programs in background in Windows.

Comment: @abilasher, yes, that's because `ng` command is stopped. See my update.

Comment: @abilasher, actually, take a look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/591084/297708) for running both programs on Windows

Comment: @MaxKoretskyi its throwing error for me `Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'serve'.

Answer (score 1):

From a web browser open http://localhost:4200

To kill the ngCli development server use ctrl+c in the command prompt.

You won't be able to run other commands in the command prompt while the development server is running. Simply open another command prompt to run other tasks.